# Decreasing interval using derivation is different from inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, power-series

I have the following function $a_n=$ $\frac{\ln{n}}{n}$ and I want to find its decreasing interval from (0 $,$ $\infty$). I tried two methods and got different results.

if I take the derivative i will get $\frac{1-\ln{n}}{n^2}$. So the decreasing interval is from (1,$\infty$).

But if I take use the following 
$a_{n+1} \leq a_n \implies \frac{\ln{n+1}}{n+1} \leq \frac{\ln{n}}{n} $ which is true for $n\geq3$.

How am I getting different values? is there a mistake with the second method ?

Comment: First solution has a fairly trivial mistake: $1-\ln n<0$ is equivalent with $n>e$.

Comment: So it is not decreasing from 1 to $\infty$. so I guess the first method is wrong and the second is correct. am i right @StinkingBishop ?

Comment: It is decreasing from $e$ to infinity. The first method, can be used alright, but you would need to, additionally, manually check which value is bigger: $a_2$ or $a_3$, as $e$ is between $2$ and $3$.